# How can I add points onto a seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

How can I put points onto a `seaborn` bar plot? The following code produces the bar plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
seaborn.set_context('talk')

data_df = pandas.DataFrame([3, 1, 2, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()
points_df = pandas.DataFrame([3.5, 0.5, 1.75, 4.25], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()
plt.figure()
seaborn.barplot(data=data_df)

plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I now add the data in `points_df` as red points on this graph?

Comment: Do the down voters have any suggestions for improvements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame([3, 1, 2, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()
points_df = pd.DataFrame([3.5, 0.5, 1.75, 4.25], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()

plt.figure()
sns.barplot(data=data_df)
sns.scatterplot(data=points_df.T, legend=False, zorder=10)
```

for some reason, I had to change the `zorder` of the points, otherwise some would be hidden behind the bars

[image]

Comment: Beaten to the punch by @Bazingaa. I actually think using `pointplot` might be better, especially if you'd like to have the points joined.

Comment: Roger that :) :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `pointplot` from `seaborn` for plotting the red points using `join=False` and using `zorder` to bring the dots to the front. The key here is to define an axis instance `ax` and pass it to both the plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
seaborn.set_context('talk')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data_df = pd.DataFrame([3, 1, 2, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()
points_df = pd.DataFrame([3.5, 0.5, 1.75, 4.25], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose()
sns.barplot(data=data_df, ax=ax, zorder=0)
sns.pointplot(data=points_df, join=False, color='red', ax=ax, zorder=1)
```

[image]